# Microsoft.XMLHTTP in C#.NET

Tags: c#, xml, asp-classic

I currently have a  project converting asp classic codes to C#, then i came into this section of the code...

```
    Function sendRequest(sRequest) //sRequest is XML data
    Dim sResponse

    Set oHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

    oHTTP.open                  HTTP_POST, WDL_URL_PREFIX, false
    oHTTP.setRequestHeader      "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    oHTTP.send                  "IN=" & Server.UrlEncode(sRequest)

    sResponse = oHTTP.responseText
    sendRequest = sResponse
    End Function
```

The function basically sends XML data via HTTP and it uses Microsoft.XMLHTTP object. Now, what is the equivalent of this object(Microsoft.XMLHTTP) in .NET because I don't want to use this legacy classic DLL...

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .NET, the easiest implementation there is simply:

```
string url = ..., request = ...;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var response = client.UploadValues(url, new NameValueCollection {
        {"IN",request}
    });
    var text = client.Encoding.GetString(response);
}
```

I'm using C# here, but it applies to VB too.

Comment: thanks but I get error in new NameValueCollection {{"IN",request} //wrong overload

Comment: +1, you are right that WebClient is more appropriate than WebRequest for this use case. (Deleted my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into `System.Net.WebRequest`: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx