# XMLHTTP60 and VB.net

Tags: vb.net, xmlhttprequest

I am converting a VBA program into vb.net, in this app I need to retrieve a xml doc from a web service. My code is looking like that:

```
Private Function GetDartPricing(xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, DARTID As String) As Boolean

        GetDartPricing = False
        xhr.open("GET", "https://xxx Deal ID='" & DARTID & "'", True)
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic Domain=AUTH;UserID=" & CommonModule.DARTUserName & ";Password=" & CommonModule.DARTPassword)
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml")
        xhr.send()
        Do While xhr.readyState <> 4
            Select Case xhr.readyState
                Case 1
                    Me.LabelDART.Text = "DART Connection Established"
                Case 2
                    Me.LabelDART.Text = "Request Received"
                Case 3
                    Me.LabelDART.Text = "Processing Request"
                Case 4
                    Me.LabelDART.Text = "DART Request Complete"
            End Select
        Loop
        Select Case xhr.status
            Case 200
                If xhr.responseText = "Invalid input/No corresponding data found" Then
                    GetDartPricing = False
                    Me.LabelDART.Text = "Not Found"
                Else
                    GetDartPricing = True
                End If
            Case 401
                GetDartPricing = False
                Me.LabelDART.Text = "User Authentication Failed"
            Case 12007
                GetDartPricing = False
                Me.LabelDART.Text = "Download Failed"
            Case Else
                GetDartPricing = False
                Me.LabelDART.Text = "Download Failed"
        End Select
        Return GetDartPricing
    End Function
```

I know I am missing something because this is not working (when the same works in VBA)
when debugging I get the following error messages:

'xhr.status' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

and my readyState value stays to 1

Can someone helps me or point me to the right direction?
thanks.

Comment: NET framework has a manged version of MSXML2, why not using it?

Comment: Not sure I understand, this is what I do. but I probably missing something somewhere as my xhr.readyState stays to 1. What I don't understand is if I need to 'refresh the readystate or if this is a problem with the web service (even if the VB6/VBA app is working fine)

Comment: In your VBA original project you added reference to MSXML2 COM object. In NET Framework you have native DOT NET classes that [do the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189934/whats-the-equivalent-of-xmlhttp-from-vb6-in-c-sharp-net-2005) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056504/microsoft-xmlhttp-in-c-net) then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882861/what-are-net-classes-to-replace-the-old-msxml2-serverxmlhttp)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `True` value in this line to `False`; it worked for me.

```
xhr.open("GET", "https://xxx Deal ID='" & DARTID & "'", True)
```